# Reading an Encrypt file

Tags: java, encryption, java-8

I am writing an application that encrypts a list of `Employee` into a text file. I was able to encrypt the `Employee`s list to a text file. When I try to decrypt it back, I am getting some error saying

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.reading.employee.blueprint.Employee cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.List

**This is an example of the code I am working on.**

```
private static byte[] encryptingAFile(List<Employee> list) {
    byte[] empList, textEncrypted = null;

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream object = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray);

        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

        Cipher desCipher;
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String s;

        for (Employee employee: list) {
            object.writeObject(employee);
        }

        empList = byteArray.toByteArray();
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(empList);

        Files.write(Paths.get("Encrypt.txt"), textEncrypted);

        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(textDecrypted);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        List<Employee > result = (List<Employee>) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return textEncrypted;
}
```

**I was hoping that someone could help me.**

Answer (score 2):

When you write the objects to the `ObjectOutputStream`, you write each `Employee` one at a time, you don't write a single list object. So when you read them back in, you don't get a single list object back. Either you need to write the whole list to the stream in the first place, or you need to read the `Employee` objects back one at a time.

Comment: Is there an example you could show me how to read it back one at a time, please. I am little new to java, and this is actually my first time encrypting and decrypting a file.

Comment: @William the point made is that while you are encrypting the `Employee`s one at a time, you're trying to decrypt the object as a `List<Employee>` which is why you get a ClassCastException.

Comment: Thank so much for hint. I did what your told me and it work!.